# Invoke custom ember helper in code

Tags: ember.js

I have a custom helper 'myHelperFunction' and I want to call the method in code, how can i do that?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function myHelperFunction(params) {
    return myData;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(myHelperFunction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was:

my-function.js (Helper)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {
    ...
    return myData;
});
```

and then:

```
import myFunction from '../helpers/my-function';

...
myFunction.compute([param1, param2])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it using `import` keyword in file where you want to use it:

```
import myHelperFunction from '../helpers/my-helper-function';

let result = myHelperFunction();
```

Comment: Important to note the reason why it doesn't work. If you console log myHelperFunction you will see by default it will export the function as compute. Hence why Mario Gomez needed to do myFunction.compute in his answer. Also worth noting that if you accept multiple parameters you must pass them as an array (how handlebars does it)